# consulta para agrupar y sumar datos en php y mysql

Tags: mysql, php7

hola gente como estan? espero que me puedan ayudar tengo un problema necesito hacer una consulta complicada a mysql al menos para mi. seria algo asi,consulta en un grupo de ventas delimitado por dos fechas que en casi serian $valor2 y $valor3, y $valor seria el id del json que se muestra abajo, el problema es que devuelve null

```
SELECT sum(json_extract(productos, '$[*].cantidad') as cantidad, 
       sum(json_extract(productos, '$[*].precio_venta') as precio_venta
FROM ventas 
WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2020-03-16 00:00:00' AND '2020-03-16 23:00:00' AND 
      json_extract(productos, '$[*].descripcion') like '%16%'
```

tengo que hacer un listado de ventas por categoria y ordenarlo en forma decreciente, los datos de la ventam estan en formato json es el siguiente

```
[{"id":"16","descripcion":"PAPEL SAN GABRIEL 90m X 4 ROLLOS BLANCO","cantidad":"1","sucursal":"sucursal2","categoria":"8","precioCompra":"79.83","ganancia":"15.17","precioVenta":"95","total":"95"},{"id":"15","descripcion":"AYUDIN DESODORANTE","cantidad":"1","sucursal":"sucursal2","categoria":"7","precioCompra":"25.55","ganancia":"4.09","precioVenta":"29.64","total":"29.64"}]
```

Comment: Las claves del JSON se llaman `precioVenta` y `precioCompra` y en la consulta estás usando `precio_venta` y `precio_compra`. Otro error en tu JSON es que esos datos aparecen como cadena, cuando deberían ser enteros. No tengo experiencia usando JSON en MySQL, no sé si funcionará con esos datos así.

Comment: SELECT sum(json_extract(productos, '$[*].cantidad') as cantidad, 
       sum(json_extract(productos, '$[*].precioVenta ') as precio_venta
FROM ventas 
WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2020-03-16 00:00:00' AND '2020-03-16 23:00:00' AND 
      json_extract(productos, '$[*].descripcion') like '%16%'  lo corregi  a esta forma y sigue igual